# Use netconsole to debug with kernel crash

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Recently I use netconsole to debug with kernel crash.

However the log prints too fast, it seems that netconsole cannot transfer all the log in real-time, since ehternet allows maximum payload of each transmission packet is 1450byte?

Also on the crashed computer, I cannot see any oops message neither, so I cannot debug with it by using gdb.

Any recommended debug techniques to debug with this situation?